# Как забрать значение из json если разный регистр букв

Tags: java, json

Как составить запрос что бы получить значение "Usd" к примеру

Полученный ответ:

```
{
"RUR":{Balance: 0}
"Usd":{Balance: 0}
}
```

Доступно для использования нижнем регистре rur, usd
Как то так не получается:

```
BigDecimal balance = response.getJsonObject("usd").getJsonNumber("Balance").bigDecimalValue()
```

Comment: какой тип у `response`? а если попробовать соблюдать регистр, то получается?

Comment: javax.json.JsonObject response, при соблюдении регистра букв все нормально, просто заранее неизвестно в каком регистре придет ответ, вот и нужно как то сделать совместимым Usd и usd или USD и usd чтобы получить значение потому что данные приходят динамические и заранее их можно не знать.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) нужно настроить механизм сопоставления элементов (mapper), чтобы он не учитывал регистр букв.

Пример:

Допустим, у нас есть класс:

```
public class CarInfo {  
    private String model;
    private String year;
    //getter, setter, constructor
}
```

И два JSON-блока данных, которые мы хотим загрузить:

```
{
    "model":"Tesla",
    "year":"2015"
}
```

и

```
{
    "ModeL":"Tesla",
    "YeaR":"2015"
}
```

Конфигурируем Jackson перед загрузкой (см. `objectMapper.configure()`) и загружаем объект из JSON:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);  
CarInfo info = objectMapper.readValue(data, CarInfo.class); //'data' содержит JSON, который надо загрузить
```

источник: http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/27/case-insensitive-deserialization-in/